# How to make Highcharts work with meteor v1.9.3

Tags: meteor, highcharts

I am trying to create an app that uses Highcharts to make a graph on the screen. I cannot figure out how to download highcharts so that it works with meteor version 1.9.3.

I tried to download highcharts using `npm install highcharts --save` but this is not working with the meteor version I have. From Node.js I get this response

```
$meteor npm install --save highcharts
+ highcharts@7.1.2
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 605 packages in 57.929s
found 2 moderate severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

When I run `npm audit fix` it is not able to fix the vulnerabilities. Then when I run my project I cannot get the highchart graph to show up. Also when I was looking for a solution I found the following website which states that `npm install --save highcharts` won't work on versions of meteor above 1.3.
https://atmospherejs.com/highcharts/highcharts-meteor 
Is there another way to download Highcharts?

Comment: ` but this is not working with the meteor version I have` - is a very broad statement. Can you be a bit more specific on that? For example are there any errors? Can you please add a minimal reproducible code example?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I have edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: `I cannot get the highchart graph to show up` this is the interesting part. Please show some code of your template/component/ui where you actually try to integrate highcharts,

Comment: `won't work on versions of meteor above 1.3` - this is the statement about the highcharts meteor wrapper described in this article. Could you reproduce the issue or send a package with a project and instructions on how to run it?